# Keras model concat: Attribute and Value error

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, concatenation

This is a keras model I have made based on the paper Liu, Gibson, et al 2017 (https://arxiv.org/abs/1708.09022). It can be seen in fig1.

I have 3 questions-

1. I am not sure if I am correctly using concatenate as per the paper.
2. I am getting AttributeError: 'KerasTensor' object has no attribute 'add' on model4.add flatten. This error didn't show up earlier
3. Earlier, the only error was ValueError: A `Concatenate` layer requires inputs with matching shapes except for the concat axis. Got inputs shapes: [(None, 310, 1, 16), (None, 310, 1, 32), (None, 310, 1, 64)], which I am also not sure how to deal with.

```
model1= Sequential()
model2= Sequential()
model3= Sequential()
model4= Sequential()

input_sh = (619,2,1)

model1.add(Convolution1D(filters=16, kernel_size=21, padding='same', activation='LeakyReLU', input_shape=input_sh))
model1.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2), padding='same')) 
model1.add(BatchNormalization())
model1.summary()

model2.add(Convolution1D(filters=32, kernel_size=11, padding='same', activation='LeakyReLU', input_shape= input_sh))
model2.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2), padding='same'))
model2.add(BatchNormalization())
model2.summary()

model3.add(Convolution1D(filters=64, kernel_size=5, padding='same', activation='LeakyReLU', input_shape= input_sh))
model3.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2), padding='same'))
model3.add(BatchNormalization())
model3.summary()

model4 = concatenate([model1.output, model2.output, model3.output], axis= -1)

model4.add(Flatten()) # Line with error
model4.add(Dense(2048, activation='tanh'))
model4.add(Dropout(.5))
model4.add(Dense(len(dic), activation="softmax")) #len(dic) = 19
model4.summary()
```

The output is as follows-

```
Model: "sequential_59"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
conv1d_45 (Conv1D)           (None, 619, 2, 16)        352       
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_45 (MaxPooling (None, 310, 1, 16)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_45 (Batc (None, 310, 1, 16)        64        
=================================================================
Total params: 416
Trainable params: 384
Non-trainable params: 32
_________________________________________________________________
Model: "sequential_60"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
conv1d_46 (Conv1D)           (None, 619, 2, 32)        384       
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_46 (MaxPooling (None, 310, 1, 32)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_46 (Batc (None, 310, 1, 32)        128       
=================================================================
Total params: 512
Trainable params: 448
Non-trainable params: 64
_________________________________________________________________
Model: "sequential_61"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
conv1d_47 (Conv1D)           (None, 619, 2, 64)        384       
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_47 (MaxPooling (None, 310, 1, 64)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_47 (Batc (None, 310, 1, 64)        256       
=================================================================
Total params: 640
Trainable params: 512
Non-trainable params: 128
_________________________________________________________________
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-25-bf7ad914aa4e> in <module>()
     44 model4 = concatenate([model1.output, model2.output, model3.output], axis= -1)
     45 
---> 46 model4.add(Flatten())
     47 model4.add(Dense(2048, activation='tanh'))
     48 model4.add(Dropout(.5))
 
AttributeError: 'KerasTensor' object has no attribute 'add'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `Functional()` API in order to solve your problem (I haven't read the paper, but here is how you can combine models and get a final output).

I used 'relu' activation for simplicity purposes (ensure you use `keras` inside `tensorflow`)

Here is the code that should work:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras import *
from tensorflow.keras.layers import *

model1= Sequential()
model2= Sequential()
model3= Sequential()

input_sh = (619,2,1)

model1.add(Convolution1D(filters=16, kernel_size=21, padding='same', activation='relu', input_shape=input_sh))
model1.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2), padding='same')) 
model1.add(BatchNormalization())
model1.summary()

model2.add(Convolution1D(filters=32, kernel_size=11, padding='same', activation='relu', input_shape= input_sh))
model2.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2), padding='same'))
model2.add(BatchNormalization())
model2.summary()

model3.add(Convolution1D(filters=64, kernel_size=5, padding='same', activation='relu', input_shape= input_sh))
model3.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2), padding='same'))
model3.add(BatchNormalization())
model3.summary()

concatenated = concatenate([model1.output, model2.output, model3.output], axis=-1)
x = Dense(64, activation='relu')(concatenated)
x = Flatten()(x)
x = Dropout(.5)(x)
x = Dense(19, activation="softmax")(x)
final_model = Model(inputs=[model1.input,model2.input,model3.input],outputs=x)
final_model.summary()





Model: "functional_3"
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                    Output Shape         Param #     Connected to                     
==================================================================================================
conv1d_15_input (InputLayer)    [(None, 619, 2, 1)]  0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv1d_16_input (InputLayer)    [(None, 619, 2, 1)]  0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv1d_17_input (InputLayer)    [(None, 619, 2, 1)]  0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv1d_15 (Conv1D)              (None, 619, 2, 16)   352         conv1d_15_input[0][0]            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv1d_16 (Conv1D)              (None, 619, 2, 32)   384         conv1d_16_input[0][0]            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv1d_17 (Conv1D)              (None, 619, 2, 64)   384         conv1d_17_input[0][0]            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_15 (MaxPooling2D) (None, 310, 1, 16)   0           conv1d_15[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_16 (MaxPooling2D) (None, 310, 1, 32)   0           conv1d_16[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_17 (MaxPooling2D) (None, 310, 1, 64)   0           conv1d_17[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_15 (BatchNo (None, 310, 1, 16)   64          max_pooling2d_15[0][0]           
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_16 (BatchNo (None, 310, 1, 32)   128         max_pooling2d_16[0][0]           
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_17 (BatchNo (None, 310, 1, 64)   256         max_pooling2d_17[0][0]           
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
concatenate_5 (Concatenate)     (None, 310, 1, 112)  0           batch_normalization_15[0][0]     
                                                                 batch_normalization_16[0][0]     
                                                                 batch_normalization_17[0][0]     
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_5 (Dense)                 (None, 310, 1, 64)   7232        concatenate_5[0][0]              
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
flatten_3 (Flatten)             (None, 19840)        0           dense_5[0][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dropout_3 (Dropout)             (None, 19840)        0           flatten_3[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_6 (Dense)                 (None, 19)           376979      dropout_3[0][0]                  
==================================================================================================
Total params: 385,779
Trainable params: 385,555
Non-trainable params: 224
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
I was able to create the final model, however, when I did this,

```final_model.fit(x, y, validation_data = (tSX, tAX), epochs=50, batch_size=10, verbose=2)```

It showed,

```ValueError: Layer model_1 expects 3 input(s), but it received 1 input tensors. Inputs received: [<tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:0' shape=(None, 619, 2, 1) dtype=float32>]```

Comment: Okay, that is a totally different question. Stackoverflow rules do suggest to ask each question separately, not multiple question under "one" question. If my answer solved your problem, it is usually accepted by the one how asked the question. As for the other questions, please proceed to ask a new question.

Comment: You are welcome. I am telling you this intentionally because reviewers tend to close the questions which are too broad/contain too many subquestions and I want newcomers to be aware, thereby avoiding the deletion/closing of their questions.