# ValueError: Layer model expects 3 input(s), but it received 1 input tensors. Inputs received: [<tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:0' shape=(None, 619, 2, 1)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

```
ValueError: Layer model expects 3 input(s), but it received 1 input tensors. Inputs received: [<tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:0' shape=(None, 619, 2, 1) dtype=float32>]
```

This is the complete error that I am getting.

I have to concatenate 3 models and then add 2 dense layers before using model.fit. I got the concatenated model which can be seen in the summary, but I am getting this error while fitting the model and I am unsure as to what it means and what I am supposed to do with it.

I have made based on the paper Liu, Gibson, et al 2017 (https://arxiv.org/abs/1708.09022). The model can be seen in fig1.

Previous post for reference: [Keras model concat: Attribute and Value error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68229187/keras-model-concat-attribute-and-value-error)

The code is as follows-

```
input_sh = (619,2,1)

model1.add(Convolution1D(filters=16, kernel_size=21, padding='same', activation='LeakyReLU', input_shape=input_sh))
model1.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2), padding='same'))
model1.add(BatchNormalization())
model1.summary()

model2.add(Convolution1D(filters=32, kernel_size=11, padding='same', activation='LeakyReLU', input_shape= input_sh))
model2.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2), padding='same'))
model2.add(BatchNormalization())
model2.summary()

model3.add(Convolution1D(filters=64, kernel_size=5, padding='same', activation='LeakyReLU', input_shape= input_sh))
model3.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2), padding='same'))
model3.add(BatchNormalization())
model3.summary()

concatenated = concatenate([model1.output, model2.output, model3.output], axis=-1)
m = Dense(2048, activation='tanh')(concatenated)
m = Flatten()(m)
m = Dropout(.5)(m)
m = Dense(len(dic), activation="softmax")(m) #len(dic) = 19 here
final_model = Model(inputs=[model1.input,model2.input,model3.input],outputs=m)
final_model.summary()

final_model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam',  metrics=['accuracy'])
final_model.fit(x, y, validation_data = (tSX, tAX), epochs=50, batch_size=10, verbose=2) #line with error
```

The output is-

````
Model: "sequential"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
conv1d (Conv1D)              (None, 619, 2, 16)        352       
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d (MaxPooling2D) (None, 310, 1, 16)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization (BatchNo (None, 310, 1, 16)        64        
=================================================================
Total params: 416
Trainable params: 384
Non-trainable params: 32
_________________________________________________________________
Model: "sequential_1"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
conv1d_1 (Conv1D)            (None, 619, 2, 32)        384       
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_1 (MaxPooling2 (None, 310, 1, 32)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_1 (Batch (None, 310, 1, 32)        128       
=================================================================
Total params: 512
Trainable params: 448
Non-trainable params: 64
_________________________________________________________________
Model: "sequential_2"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
conv1d_2 (Conv1D)            (None, 619, 2, 64)        384       
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_2 (MaxPooling2 (None, 310, 1, 64)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_2 (Batch (None, 310, 1, 64)        256       
=================================================================
Total params: 640
Trainable params: 512
Non-trainable params: 128
_________________________________________________________________
Model: "model"
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                    Output Shape         Param #     Connected to                     
==================================================================================================
conv1d_input (InputLayer)       [(None, 619, 2, 1)]  0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv1d_1_input (InputLayer)     [(None, 619, 2, 1)]  0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv1d_2_input (InputLayer)     [(None, 619, 2, 1)]  0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv1d (Conv1D)                 (None, 619, 2, 16)   352         conv1d_input[0][0]               
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv1d_1 (Conv1D)               (None, 619, 2, 32)   384         conv1d_1_input[0][0]             
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv1d_2 (Conv1D)               (None, 619, 2, 64)   384         conv1d_2_input[0][0]             
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d (MaxPooling2D)    (None, 310, 1, 16)   0           conv1d[0][0]                     
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_1 (MaxPooling2D)  (None, 310, 1, 32)   0           conv1d_1[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_2 (MaxPooling2D)  (None, 310, 1, 64)   0           conv1d_2[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization (BatchNorma (None, 310, 1, 16)   64          max_pooling2d[0][0]              
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_1 (BatchNor (None, 310, 1, 32)   128         max_pooling2d_1[0][0]            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_2 (BatchNor (None, 310, 1, 64)   256         max_pooling2d_2[0][0]            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
concatenate (Concatenate)       (None, 310, 1, 112)  0           batch_normalization[0][0]        
                                                                 batch_normalization_1[0][0]      
                                                                 batch_normalization_2[0][0]      
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense (Dense)                   (None, 310, 1, 2048) 231424      concatenate[0][0]                
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
flatten (Flatten)               (None, 634880)       0           dense[0][0]                      
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dropout (Dropout)               (None, 634880)       0           flatten[0][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)                 (None, 19)           12062739    dropout[0][0]                    
==================================================================================================
Total params: 12,295,731
Trainable params: 12,295,507
Non-trainable params: 224
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
Epoch 1/50
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-e139c1d87ef7> in <module>()
     63 
     64 final_model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam',  metrics=['accuracy'])
---> 65 final_model.fit(x, y, validation_data = (tSX, tAX), epochs=50, batch_size=10, verbose=2)
     66 
     67 # # _, accuracy = model.evaluate(x, y)

9 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/func_graph.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    984           except Exception as e:  # pylint:disable=broad-except
    985             if hasattr(e, "ag_error_metadata"):
--> 986               raise e.ag_error_metadata.to_exception(e)
    987             else:
    988               raise

ValueError: in user code:

    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:855 train_function  *
        return step_function(self, iterator)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:845 step_function  **
        outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:1285 run
        return self._extended.call_for_each_replica(fn, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:2833 call_for_each_replica
        return self._call_for_each_replica(fn, args, kwargs)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:3608 _call_for_each_replica
        return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:838 run_step  **
        outputs = model.train_step(data)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:795 train_step
        y_pred = self(x, training=True)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py:1013 __call__
        input_spec.assert_input_compatibility(self.input_spec, inputs, self.name)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/input_spec.py:203 assert_input_compatibility
        ' input tensors. Inputs received: ' + str(inputs))

    ValueError: Layer model expects 3 input(s), but it received 1 input tensors. Inputs received: [<tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:0' shape=(None, 619, 2, 1) dtype=float32>]```
````

Comment: Wait, I don't think what you want is 3 models, it's 1 model with 9 layers.

Comment: Edit: I was confused regarding that as well. But if it is a 9 layer model, what does concat exactly mean here?

Comment: SRY, I thought you want  model but get the error but after i saw the paper no I think you want something else. I'm writing the answer

Comment: I have edited my comment right after I saw your edit, was confused there since the start, my original model had 9 layers but I don't know what concat means there.

Comment: Now I'm confusing too, do you actually need Concat?

Comment: The diagram makes me feel like the model run `input -> layer1 -> layer2 -> layer3 -> FC` but if you actually use concat that means each layer has the same input.

Comment: In the paper, fig1 shows a concat layer. In the paragraphs above the figure, they mention "To avoid overfitting the model to the data, we applied batch
normalization after each layer and dropout after the first fully connected layer"

Comment: Batchnorm is one thing. Concat is another. Concat is like you stack an image on top of another image. And I don't see the word "concat" anywhere else in the paper.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234466/discussion-between-kshitij-thakur-and-natthaphon-hongcharoen).